# Snapping sound in my ankle

Tags: injury

I have a snapping sound in my right ankle. It was bad but I started to wear braces most of the time, even while I am working out. That does help a lot, and it feels stronger and more comfortable, but the snapping is still there (although less than before). Are there some exercises to do that will help to minimize or stop the sound forever? I am kind of addicted to working out and can't bear the idea of leaving the gym because of this kind of injury.

Answer (score 5):

You could be experiencing gas escaping, or tendons popping in and out of place.  See this [everyday mystery about cracking joints](http://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/joint.html).  Due to the repetitive nature of this affliction you have, it very well [may have to do with the tendons](http://mcr.coreconcepts.com.sg/snapping-ankle/).

I would recommend:

- Seeing an experienced Sports Physician, Orthopedic Surgeon or Sports Physiotherapist (as per the second link)
- Incorporate stretching exercises on your ankle

As to the braces:

- Braces are intended to be a temporary stability helper when you are injured, not a long term solution.  Example, to provide stability after you sprain your ankle until the tendons heal.
- When you use a brace, your supporting muscles are not being used, which causes them to become weaker.  In short you will be at greater risk of injury any time you do not use the brace.

If you choose to ween off of the brace, you'll have to go light until you build your ankles back up.  I.e. start light, and build intensity a little at a time, consistently.